# Firebase Realtime Database loading indication on Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase provides awesome Realtime Database service, but it is a bit outstanding from my, and I suggest that not only my, experience when this engine is used as main local storage (offline mode).

What do I expect when app is requesting some data is to see some indication of the process. But I have not found any direct functionality to get it working.

So, I created custom solution and would like to get reviews from community.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple: bind a ValueEventListener to some version tag which creates a request with SingleValueEvent callback updating data and changing its state.

Suppose, i have a `User` object and for versioning I add `ver` property with timestamp content:

```
users : {
    id : {
       name : 'Mr. Anderson',
       ver : '<timestamp>'
    }
}
```

To see data state I introduce `enum State`, `interface StateIndicatable`, `interface OnStateChangeListener`:

```
enum State{ INIT, LOADING, LOADED, FAILED }

interface OnStateChangeListener{
    void stateChanged(State newState);
}

interface StateIndicatable{
    State getState();
    void setOnStateChangeListener(OnStateChangeListener listener);
    void clearOnStateChangeListener();
}
```

I wouldn't like to change the `User` model and I will use a wrapper which will exist on the level of view/presentation/view_model:

I'd like to create an abstract Wrapper around any versionable model:

```
abstract class FirebaseVersionedModelWrapper<M> implements StateIndicatable{

    int version;
    protected WeakReference<M> modelRef;
    State state;
    OnStateChangeListener onStateChangeListener;
    DatabaseReference verRef;

    FirebaseVersionedModelWrapper(M model, String firebasePath, OnStateChangeListener onStateChangeListener){
        this.modelRef = new WeakReference(model);
        this.state = State.INIT;
        this.onStateChangeListener = onStateChangeListener;
        verRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(firebasePath + "/ver");
        verRef.keepSynced(true);


        verRef.addValueEventListener(
                new OnValueEventListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(modelRef.get()==null){
                            verRef.removeEventListener(this);
                            return;
                        }

                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("ver"){
                            if(dataSnapshot.child("ver").getValue(Integer.class) != version){
                                requestUpdate();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            setState(State.FAILED);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        if(modelRef.get()==null){
                            verRef.removeEventListener(this);
                            return;
                        }

                        setState(State.FAILED);
                    }
                }
            );

    }

    private void requestUpdate(){
        setState(State.LOADING);

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance
            .getReference(firebasePath);
        ref.keepSynced(true);

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new OnValueEventListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        M model = modelRef.get();
                        if (model==null) return;
                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("ver")){
                            version = dataSnapshot.child("ver").getValue(Integer.class);
                            setFields(model, dataSnapshot);
                            setState(State.LOADED);
                        }
                        else{
                            setState(State.FAILED);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                       setState(State.FAILED);
                    }
                }
            );
    }

    private void setState(State newState){
        if (this.state == newState) return;

        this.state = newState;

        if (onStateChangeListener != null)
          onStateChangeListener.stateChanged(newState);
    }

    @Override
    public State getState(){
        return this.state;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnStateChangeListener(OnStateChangeListener listener){
        this.onStateChangeListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void clearOnStateChangeListener(){
        this.onStateChangeListener = null;
    }

    protected abstract void setFields(M model, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot);

}
```

Here `DatabaseReference#keepSynced(true)` is called to be sure that the request on data path will return fresh data. This is discussable approach and not completely confirmed in my practice now.

Then I wrap the `User` into `UserWrapper`:

```
class UserWrapper extends FirebaseVersionedModelWrapper<User>{

    FirebasedUser(User userModel, String userPath, OnStateChangeListener listener){
        super(userModel, userPath, listener);
    }

    @Override
    void setFields(User model, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        // setting values for model
    }
}
```

And eventually I can instantiate the wrapper and bind indication routines to OnStateChangeListener callback:

```
User user = new User();

UserWrapper wrapper = new UserWrapper(
    user,
    new OnStateChangeListener(){

        @Override
        void stateChanged(State newState){
            if(newState == State.LOADED){
                showUserDetails();
            }
            else if(newState == State.FAILD){
                showErrorState();
            }
            else{
                showLoadingIndicator();
            }
        }

    }
);
```

Well, as I said, any opinions and alternative solutions posted here are much appreciated!

*the code is typed from memory and may have mistakes*